# syntax error on token "extends" delete this token

Tags: java

am working on a cloud computing program and i keep getting this error..syntax error on token "extends" delete this token..please am totally lost and how can i correct it?
i have tried switching characters and debugging but it does not work.
my code:(this is just a part of the many modules i have and it seems not to be correct)

```
import java.rmi.*;

public interface extends Remote {
   public void Mess() throws Remote Exception;
}
```

please really need help!!

Comment: simply put the interface name after the interface keyword or better create an anonymous inner class

Answer (score 2):

What is the name of this interface you are trying to define? You have to give a name, for example  something like this:

```
public interface MyRemote extends Remote {
```

Answer (score 1):

You miss the Name of your Interface. the Syntax should be:

```
public  interface <Interface_name> extends   Remote{
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a name to the interface.  It does not have a name